# Why is it possible to write QVariant to QDataStream when QDataStream dosen't have such method?

Tags: c++, qt, qdatastream

I can write a QVariant to a QDataStream and read a QVariant from a QDataStream without a problem.

```
QByteArray byteArray;

QDataStream outStream(&byteArray, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QVariant outVar(QString("hello"));
outStream << outVar;

QVariant inVar;
QDataStream inStream(&byteArray, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
inStream >> inVar;
```

My problem is, how does above code compile and work properly when QDataStream does not have method `operator<<(QVariant v)` ?

Comment: The operator could be declared outside of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `operator<<` is declared in QVariant.

According to [QDataStream](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdatastream.html#reading-and-writing-other-qt-classes),

> In addition to the overloaded stream operators documented here, any Qt classes that you might want to serialize to a QDataStream will have appropriate stream operators declared as non-member of the class.

In the source code of QVariant, you can find the two non-member functions (unfortunately, they are not listed in the documentation of QVariant) :

```
QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream &s, const QVariant &p)
QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream &s, QVariant &p)
```